# No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found

Tags: javascript, java, android, iphone, cordova

hi guys can you help me how i add key access in xcode i try build my application cordova but it show this error No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found. can u help me thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is probably occurring because an existing provision profile expired and there is no valid profile to work with.

You would need to log into the Apple Developer portal at developer.apple.com, navigate to the Certificates, IDs & Profiles page and then create the Provisioning Profile for your application.  The section for Provisioning Profiles is at the bottom of this page.

Once the Profile has been created, you would open the General settings of your project in XCode and update the Signing section for your application.  Make sure that your team is set up correctly and if you are managing signing manually, select the profile that you created.

Comment: thank you sur can i build my app without key , because  i have account at developper.apple.com but  Certificates, IDs & Profiles page  is not exist in my account  how do i show it

Comment: how i create Generating the Distribution Certificate & Provisioning Profile . can i create Generating the Distribution Certificate & Provisioning Profile free help me and thank advance

Comment: How do you have your project set up and how are you attempting to build the application?  To my knowledge, you will not be able to build a distributable iOS application without a paid developer account with Apple.